# How to edit filenames in bulk using regex?

Tags: regex, macos, terminal, osx-yosemite

I don't even know if this is possible.

I have over 4 terabytes of MP3 files and I need a much faster way of editing files.  I use a Mac running Yosemite if that makes any difference.

Here is a sample list of files
[image: Here is a sample list of files]

In bulk, how do I remove the "Elton John", space, hyphen, space, track number, and space from the names of these files, and only leave the track name and file format?  Can it be done using terminal and if so, what's the command?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
brew install rename
rename -v 's/\s*Elton John\s*-\s*\d+\s*-(.*)/$1/' *.mp3
```

You can use the `-n` option first to see what would be the changes without affecting the files name.